# Unable to connect to SQl Server 2008 Express / SQl Server 2005 (Local) - Error 40 (Server was not found / not accessable)

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010

I have installed VS2010 Ultimate on to my freshly installed Windows7 Machine. When I tried to connect to the 2008! express database through the Server Explorer , i get an error message 
(Screen Shot Attached)[image]

Then I installed SQL Server 2005 . Now when I try to connect to DB through SQL-Server Management Studio , I get the same error there also .
(Screen Shot Attached)[image]

During the installation process ( of VS 2010 ans SQL Server 2005 ) I never got the usual options that come during the installation of SQL Server like selecting the Authentication or Named/Default Instance etc.

Any Help ? Thanks in advance. Will uninstalling the reinstalling fix the issue ?

Will that cause any issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager` and make sure that the services are running.

If the service is running, another thing to try would be to change the name from `Anant-PC` to `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks Ardman . When I check the configuration Manager , I see that the SQL Server (SQl Express) is running    SQl Server Agent (SQl Express) and SQL Server Browser are stopped.

Comment: Tried putting "localhost" instead of machine name. But same issue

Comment: I bet that if you change your computer name to `.\SQLExpress` it will connect.  If you want to get your SQL Server 2005 installation running, you'll need to start the SQL Server 2005 services in the Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the services are running.

you can run "**net start mssqlserver**" in your command prompt on the machine Anant-pc.
Also you can try putting **.** (DOT) in place of Anant-pc computer name

Comment: Thanks Sachin .When I check the configuration Manager , I see that the SQL Server (SQl Express) is running SQl Server Agent (SQl Express) and SQL Server Browser are stopped..I tried the command from Command Prompt. But it gives an error Service Name is Invalid ...

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this issue with regards to SSMS not connecting to the SQL Server on Windows 7.  I had to deleted the SSMS Provision in the Windows 7 Firewall and re-add it.  I can now access the SQL Server through SSMS, but I still can't access it through the Server Explorer in VS2008.  If I come up with a solution to this, I will update this post.  I hope this helps.